# How to share data between Main/Renderer Processes

Tags: electron

I'm a complete Electron beginner. Let's say you are creating a simple memopad-like app and want to save something you type into a textarea in the browser window by clicking the app's [File > Save] menu, which should be a very common feature.

Menu handler should be implemented in the Main process, and the textarea is clearly in the Renderer process. I can't figure out how to access what's in the textarea from the Main process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In electron applications, communications between Main and Renderer processes is performed via ipc. Electron has [ipcMain](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) and [ipcRenderer](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer) modules used in Main and Renderer processes respectively.

For the task you have, you can send a message to the renderer process whenever the user clicked on File > Save, which will trigger saving the textarea to a file. One implementation might be like this:

```
// main process
const { app } = require('electron')

// reference to the browser window
let mainWindow
app.on('ready', () => {
  // here create your browser window and assign it to mainWindow
  mainWindow = createMainWindow()
})

// clicking File > Save menu triggers following function
const saveClicked = () => {
  // Check mainWindow exists
  if (mainWindow != null) {
    mainWindow.webContents.send('clicked::file:save')
  }
}


// renderer process (preload.js)
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

// Now you need to listen for the event you send from the main process
ipcRenderer.on('clicked::file:save', () => {
  // IMPLEMENT YOUR LOGIC HERE
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot!